# JS - как вывести дробь

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим, есть выражение

`12x-5` делить на `3y-2x`

Как вывести

[image]

не обязательно прямо как на фотографии. Думаю, вы поняли о чём я)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var nom = "12x-5"
var den = "3y-2x"

function exprToJq(expr) {
  var res = []

  expr.replace(/([a-z]+)|([^a-z]+)/gi, function (m, v, o) {
    res.push(v ? $("<var>").text(v) : $("<span>").text(o).html())
  })
  
  return res
}

$("body").append($("<div>").addClass("fr").html([
  $("<div>").html(exprToJq(nom)),
  $("<div>").html(exprToJq(den))
]))
```

```css
.fr {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.fr > * {
  padding: 0 .25em;
}

.fr > :first-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```